# Atmosphere does not invoke all callbacks for shared websocket connections

Tags: jquery, comet, atmosphere

I decided to test how atmosphere framework works with shared websocket connections (shared between browser tabs).

For this I used the sample [**chat**](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/samples/chat) with several little modification in client-side:

1. I create request as function (so it can be passed to callbacks list inside the atmosphere):

   `var request = function() {};`
2. for using shared connections I set the appropriate property to true (see [**link to docs**](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Sharing-connection-between-Browser's-windows-and-tabs)):

   `request.uuid = $.atmosphere.guid();
       request.url = '${url}';
       request.contentType = "application/json";
       request.transport = 'websocket';
       request.fallbackTransport = 'long-polling';
       request.shared = true;
       request.trackMessageLength = true;
       request.reconnect = true;
       request.connectTimeout  = -1;
       request.reconnectInterval = 5000;
       request.timeout = 300000;
       request.maxRequest = -1;`
3. I pass this request to atmosphere

   `subsocket = $.atmosphere.subscribe(request, request, request);`

And after this everything works perfect (onMessage callback is invoked every time it should be invoked) except one important thing: for other opened tabs which use shared already opened websocket connection the onMessage callback is never invoked at all. So it makes the feature useless, because I couldn't use it.

Could anybody help me with this problem? I believe I do something wrong, but I really need your help.

Comment: what browser did you used?

Comment: I use Google Chrome 39.0

Comment: As I've tested it, it doesn't invoke the onMessage. But sharing local storage worked, that means you can access it through local storage. Did you tried to remove trackMessageLength?

Comment: I tried disabling trackMessageLength feature, I'm able to receive messages in several tabs. Thank you! 
But there is another problem: I often receive onOpen event for opened tabs with shared websocket (during a mminute they do connect/disconnect several times)